# TiO2 nanotube application in cement

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, materials, reference-request, nanotechnology

I am perparing for a presentation on the application of TiO2 nanotubes in cement which is a recent topic in cement chemistry. Do you happen to have any papers (or know of any accessible on Internet) on the topic from the recent years that you can share with me? Or even if you have any information/experience to share, I would be grateful.

Comment: This is very broad. What is this *topic* do you say? Appliances? Synthesis? What?